# Web API not getting me correct result

Tags: mysql, rest, web-services, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-web-api2

I am creating a `WEB API` using `MySQL` database. The database includes three records, a meter serial number it's signal strength value and the date time. I want to send the meter serial number and then get all the records for that serial number. I am successful in sending the serial number will the URL but I am getting only the single records multiple times. Below is the controller code.

```
 public MDCEntities medEntitites = new MDCEntities();

 public HttpResponseMessage GetByMsn(string msn)
    {
        try
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found, medEntitites.tj_xhqd.Where(m=> m.zdjh == msn));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }
    }
```

The response I am getting is below

```
{
    "zdjh": "000029000033",
    "sjsj": "2017-09-20T00:01:54",
    "xhqd": "28"
},
{
    "zdjh": "000029000033",
    "sjsj": "2017-09-20T00:01:54",
    "xhqd": "28"
},
{
    "zdjh": "000029000033",
    "sjsj": "2017-09-20T00:01:54",
    "xhqd": "28"
},
{
    "zdjh": "000029000033",
    "sjsj": "2017-09-20T00:01:54",
    "xhqd": "28"
},
.
.
.
.
.
// same values are repeating again and again.
```

I have tried to see the solutions but I am unable to get help from it.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After searching again and again I managed to solve the issue by changing the query

TO:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found, medEntitites.tj_xhqd.Where(m=> m.zdjh == msn));
```

From

```
 return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found, medEntitites.tj_xhqd.Where(m=> m.zdjh == msn).Where(o=> o.sjsj <= dt).Select(m=> new { m.zdjh , m.sjsj, m.xhqd }).Distinct());
```